# Partial View modal renders on double click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm encountering this weird issue which is driving me a little crazy. I have an MVC 5 project that has a partial view which comes up as a modal when clicking a button. The issue is that, I have to click the button twice in succession for the partial view method to be triggered. Apparently this is caused when I use `$(document)` as a selector to fire the event. It works fine otherwise. I have to use `$(document)` as selector because I'm generating the buttons dynamically and using any other selector won't register click handlers. 
This is my modal container:

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the html for the button firing the event:

```
   <a class="modal-link" href="/Customer/EditGroup/@item.Customer_Group_Code">
      <img src="~/images/editIcon.png" alt="Edit" />
   </a>
```

The jQuery method I'm invoking looks like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

});
```

and here's the controller method for the view:

```
   public ActionResult EditGroup(int id)
    {
      ViewBag.id = id;
      return PartialView("_EditGroup");
    }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `$(document)`. All you doing in the 'first' click is adding the `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes. In the second click, because those attributes now exist the modal is now fired (but you adding the attributes again which is a bit pointless). You need to give more context about what your actually doing, but the `data-*` attributes need be added initially

Comment: You were right. I was basically following a tutorial which had it that way. I added the data attributes to the button which fixed it. Sill it's strange why the modal was popping up when I was using a different selector other than $(document)

Answer (score 0):

add: `return false;` to your command. This should do the fix.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(document).on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        return false;
    });    
});
```